# Validate uniqueness through join model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_many :through association setup between two tables (Post and Category). The reason I'm using has_many :through instead of HABTM is that I want to do some validation on the join table (PostCategory).

So I have 4 models in use here:

User:

```
has_many :posts
has_many :categories
```

Post:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :post_categories
has_many :categories, :through => :post_categories
```

Category:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :post_categories
has_many :posts, :through => :post_categories
```

PostCategory:

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :category
```

Basically what I want is: Users can create posts, users can also create their own categories. A user can then categorize posts (not just their posts, any posts). A post can be categorized by many different users (in different ways potentially), and a category could contain many different posts (A user could categorize N posts under a specific category of theirs).

Here's where it gets a little bit tricky for me (I'm a Rails noob). 
**A post can ONLY belong to ONE category for a given user. That is, a post CANNOT belong to more than ONE category for any user.**

What I want to be able to do is create a validation for this. I haven't been able to figure out how.
I've tried things like (inside PostCategory)

```
validates_uniqueness_of :post_id, :scope => :category_id
```

But I realize this isn't correct. This would just make sure that a post belongs to 1 category, which means that after one user categorizes the post, no other user could.

Really what I'm looking for is how to validate this in my PostCategory model (or anywhere else for that matter). I'm also not against changing my db schema if that would make things easier (I just felt that this schema was pretty straight forward).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 : use a `before_save`. In it, do a SQL look up to make sure a post with a similar category for your user doesn't exist (take care that on edit, you'll have to make sure you don't look-up for the current Post that is already in the DB)

Option 2 : custom validators : 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators

Never used them, but sounds like it can do what you want

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that didn't require custom validators, but that might be an option. You can't think of any way I could use the "validates_uniqueness_of" with ":scope" to get the validation working?

Comment: Unfortunately validates scope can;t access joined tables, therefore ... I don;t think it'll be possible

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using a custom validator so I checked your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest way is to add `user_id` to `PostCategory` and to validate uniqueness of `post_id` with `user_id` scope.

Another way is to create custom validation which checks using sql if category owner has added category to that post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems kind of redundant, the user can already be accessed via the Category (category.user). Can :scope access things like "category.user.id" ??

Comment: Nope, it cant but you could creat custom validation with join sql query

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ended up using a custom validator.